# A proof for a Gidas-Ni-Nirenberg's Theorem in their 1981's paper

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, maximum-principle

I want to ask whether my proof works for a theorem proved in Gidas-Ni-Nirenberg's second paper in 1981 ([MR0634248](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=634248)), which is much shorter than the authors' proof. Many thanks for any discussion.

**Theorem 1'** (Page 378)

> Let $u > 0$ be a $C^2$ solution of $-\Delta u = g(u)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 3$ with
>
> $u(x) = O(|x|^{-m})$ at infinity, $m>0$
>
> Assume (i) $g(s) \geq 0$ on $ 0\leq s \leq \|u\|_\infty$ and $g = g_1 + g_2$ with $g_1$ is Lipschitz and $g_2$ is continuous and non-decreasing, (ii) $g(s) = O(s^\alpha)$ near $s=0$ for some $\alpha > \frac{n+1}{m}$.
>
> Then $u$ is radially symmetric about some point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u_r < 0$ where $r$ is the radial coorinate about that point.

They shows the symmetry in $x_1$-axis by the well-known moving plane method. The first step is to show the set $\Lambda := \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}: u(x) > u(x^\lambda),  \forall x \in \Sigma_\lambda\}$ contains $[R,\infty)$ for some large $R>0$.

Notations: $x^\lambda$ is the reflection of $x$ with respect to the plane $\{ x_1 = \lambda \}$. $\Sigma_\lambda = \{ x: x_1 < \lambda\}$.

To obtain such result, they need to show **$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(u(y)) dy > 0$**. The authors **used 2 pages to prove** such thing, which is **much longer than mine.** (That's why I confused.)

**My shorter proof:**

Assume not, then $g(u(y)) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $g \geq 0$. So $u$ is harmonic and bounded. The Liouville's theorem and decay condition implies $u \equiv 0$, which contradicts to the positivity of $u$.

Comment: I ask the same question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273571/a-proof-for-a-gidas-ni-nirenbergs-theorem-in-their-1981s-paper

Comment: Do not post the same problem in two different places.

Comment: @SeanRoberson OK,thanks.